# Stop rsync from deleting large amounts of data when disk accidentally umounted

Tags: linux, unix, backup, rsync, mirroring

I use rsync to mirror my hard drive onto a couple of devices with cron.

The command is essentially this:

```
rsync -avr --delete /home/username username@example.com:/home/username
```

The problem I have is that some of the directories within the structure are on separate drives. For example /home/username/portable is a USB stick. As a result, if the cron job runs when that file system is umounted, a large amount of data is deleted from the mirror and then needs to be re-copied when it is next run with the drive mounted. This is time consuming and, of course, I assume that when I need to restore from the mirror it will be immediately after this has happened!

Could anyone suggest a good way to militate against this problem? I appreciate that two possible ways would be to see if

1. The device is mounted by grep’ing df or similar; or
2. The target directory has no contents by running du /home/username/portable or similar.

Whilst these are probably the Correct Way of dealing with this issue, both of these require manual adjustment every time a new mount point is added to the file system which does not appeal to my lazy outlook.

What I was particularly wondering is whether there is a way of getting rsync to test how much data is going to be deleted from the remote drive by running --delete? That way, the cron script could be tweaked to require manual involvement if, say, more than 1GB is going to be deleted. It would therefore provide a sanity-check against large-scale accidental data loss.

I’ve had a look through the manual but can’t see a straight-forward way of doing this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!